# Hiding text in batch

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

When when I run the code below it will say

```
stoping (-------)...
stopped (-------)...
```

or some thing like that how do i stop it from doing this so it just says

```
starting
done
```

This is the code:

```
@echo off
echo starting
net stop "Bonjour Service" /yes 2>%USERPROFILE%\temp.txt
net stop alg /yes 2>%USERPROFILE%\temp.txt
net stop "peerdists vc" /yes 2>%USERPROFILE%\temp.txt
net stop certpropsvc /yes 2>%USERPROFILE%\temp.txt
echo done
pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to redirect STDOUT to NUL:

for example:

```
net stop "Bonjour Service" /yes 1>nul 2>%USERPROFILE%\temp.txt
```

Comment: Will this work for any line of code like     Taskkill /f /im "Adobe Extension Manager" CS5.5.exe 2>%USERPROFILE%\temp.txt

Comment: yes. STDOUT  (Standard-Output) is "Channel" 1, STDERR (Standard-Error) is "Channel" 2. You can send every "Channel" separatly to another destination like this: `command 1>output.txt 2>error.txt` `>NUL` means: send it to nirvana. Note: some programs may use other "channels".